# How to check 2 values in 1 table using PHP, jQuery?

Tags: php, arrays, database, codeigniter, where-clause

Is there a way to check 2 exists values in 1 table ?

It was work just fine when i use only 1 value 'beezName' but when i added another value 'divId' it didn't work, they only check whether the 'beezName' or 'divId' exist in table. I'm trying to get :

- if beezName and divId exist then return true else false

How can i make this work? Thanks in advance

Here's my controller : Beez

```
function checkBeezExists()
{
    $beezId = $this->input->post("beezId"); 
    $beezName = $this->input->post("beezName");
    $divId = $this->input->post("divId");

    if(empty($beezId)){
        $result = $this->beez_model->checkBeezExists($beezName, $divId);
    } else {
        $result = $this->beez_model->checkBeezExists($beezName, $divId, $beezId);
}

if(empty($result)){ echo("true"); }
else { echo("false"); }
}
```

And this is my model : beez_model

```
function checkBeezExists($beezName, $divId, $beezId= 0)
{
    $this->db->select("beezName, divId");
    $this->db->from("tbl_beez");  
    $this->db->where("beezName", $beezName);   
    $this->db->where("divId", $divId); 
    $this->db->where("isDeleted", 0);
    if($beezId != 0){
        $this->db->where("beezId !=", $beezId);  
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: `($beezName, $divId, $beezId= 0)` should be `($beezName, $beezId= 0, $divId)`

Comment: Is this your actual code? because I found problems in your `validation.js` code regarding varaibles

Comment: i updated my question, i just realized there's no use using validation.js.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check `beezName and divId exist` but in your model you have wrong condition for `beezId`

try below code:

```
function checkBeezExists($beezName, $divId, $beezId= 0)
{
    $this->db->select("beezName, divId");
    $this->db->from("tbl_beez");  
    $this->db->where("beezName", $beezName);   
    $this->db->where("divId", $divId); 
    $this->db->where("isDeleted", 0);
    if($beezId != 0){
        $this->db->where("beezId", $beezId);  //<--------remove !=
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```